# ('Related Field got invalid lookup: {}'.format(lookup_name)) django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: contains

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have models like:

```
class Gtex1(models.Model):
    id = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    sample = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    gtex_s4q7_0003_sm_3nm8m = models.FloatField(db_column='GTEX-S4Q7-0003-SM-3NM8M', blank=True,    null=True)  
    gtex_qv31_1626_sm_2s1qc = models.FloatField(db_column='GTEX-QV31-1626-SM-2S1QC', blank=True,    null=True) 
    gtex_13ovi_1026_sm_5l3em = models.FloatField(db_column='GTEX-13OVI-1026-SM-5L3EM', blank=True,    null=True)


class Tcga1(models.Model):
    id = models.ForeignKey(Gtex1, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id', primary_key=True)
    sample = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    tcga_we_aaa0_06 = models.FloatField(db_column='TCGA-WE-AAA0-06', blank=True, null=True)  
    tcga_86_8668_01 = models.FloatField(db_column='TCGA-86-8668-01', blank=True, null=True)  
    tcga_d8_a146_01 = models.FloatField(db_column='TCGA-D8-A146-01', blank=True, null=True)
```

I have almost 30 models like Tcga1 having the same primary key (id) which is a foreign key from the Gtex1 model.

I am trying to do this:

```
    search_models=[models.Gtex1,models.Tcga1,models.Tcga2,models.Tcga3]
    search_results = []
    search_query='tcga_61_2111_01'
    for m in search_models:
        fields=[x for x in m._meta.get_fields()]
        search_queries=[Q(**{x.name + "__contains" : search_query}) for x in fields]
        q_object = Q()
        for query in search_queries:
            q_object = q_object | query
        results = m.objects.filter(q_object)
        search_results.append(results)

    print(search_results)
```

which is basically going through all models column names and finding search query and filter through it.

However, I am getting ERROR like:

- raise FieldError('Related Field got invalid lookup:
  {}'.format(lookup_name)) django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Related
  Field got invalid lookup: contains

If anyone can help me understand how to resolve this or any insights will be helpful and appreciated.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you try running `Tcga1.objects.filter(id__id__contains=value)` and `Tcga1.objects.filter(id__contains=value)` in a shell where `value` is some valid id for Gtex1?

Comment: @schillingt  Tcga1.objects.filter(id__contains=value) returned  this : <QuerySet [<Tcga1: Tcga1 object (value)>]>

Comment: But I want to go through column headers and implement filter.

Comment: Which field is raising the FieldError?

Comment: `in build_lookup
    raise FieldError('Related Field got invalid lookup: {}'.format(lookup_name))
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: contains`      I guess it is something I wrote with '__contains' ? while going through column headers

Comment: Sorry, I'm asking which specific field from `m._meta.get_fields()` is causing this exception.